# Where is a lookup table for rail stations in ERPC – Eastern Railroad President's Conference Codes?

Tags: data-request, usa

I have a data set with rail station information that is in ERPC for all the stations. It would be great to find a lookup table to translate these into actual station names.

Currently, the only reference I can find is in the documentation for a product called PC Miler

http://www.pcmiler.com/support/Guides/PCMILER_GeocodeFilesReferenceGuide.pdf

There are some definite rules on how they form the ERPC code: 1. Max of 9 characters 2. all spaces removed 3. Saint/Fort always translated to ST or FT

Here are some examples of the rail station names and how they translate:

Fort Worth becomes FTWORTH Cunningham becomes CUNNINGHA

In some cases it obvious what city is being referred to and in others it is not.